# Cant show icon using react-native-svg-charts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, svg, expo

I'm using [react-native-svg-charts](https://github.com/JesperLekland/react-native-svg-charts) to create a chart and I'm not able to get the image/icon to show on the chart. I looked at examples and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. My code is based on an example I got from the [examples repo](https://github.com/JesperLekland/react-native-svg-charts-examples/blob/master/storybook/stories/pie-chart/with-labels.js).

I'm getting the image from aws s3, I tried fetching the image and saving it as a temporary file but that also failed. Help!

```js
class AssetsPieChart extends Component {
 static propTypes = {
  data: arrayOf(object).isRequired,
 }

 render() {
  const { data } = this.props
  const randomColor = () => (`#${(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16)}000000`.slice(0, 7))

  const pieData = data
  .filter(el => el.value > 0)
  .map((el, index) => ({
    value: el.value,
    svg: { fill: randomColor() },
    key: `pie-${index}`,
    icon: el.icon,
  }))

  return (
   <PieChart
    style={{ height: '100%' }}
    data={pieData}
    innerRadius={100}
    outerRadius={110}
    labelRadius={150}
    renderDecorator={({
     item,
     pieCentroid,
     labelCentroid,
     index,
    }) => (
     <G key={index}>
      <Line
       x1={labelCentroid[0]}
       y1={labelCentroid[1]}
       x2={pieCentroid[0]}
       y2={pieCentroid[1]}
       stroke={item.svg.fill}
      />
      <Image
       source={{ uri: item.icon }}
       style={{ zIndex: 50 }}
       x={labelCentroid[0]}
       y={labelCentroid[1]}
      />
      <Text
       alignmentBaseline="middle"
       textAnchor="middle"
       x={labelCentroid[0]}
       y={labelCentroid[1] - 30}
       dy={-10}
      >
       {item.value}
      </Text>
     </G>
    )}
   />
  )
 }
}
```

Comment: According to the docs (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html) if you're using an image on the network you need to specify width and height. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Rajit yeah I tried :/

Comment: Btw, I'm using Image component from react-native-svg

Comment: Ah of course. I'm not sure then